# Merge multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I'am having some problems with an issue that I've encountered. I'm creating a webshop, where it is possible for a logged-in and a non-logged-in user to add products to their basket. When the user checkeouts the user will have to either log in or sign up. In case the user logs in on an existing account and that account already have a basket with products, it is a must to merge the two baskets into one. Below is my two tables (BasketTable) and (BasketProductTable).

```
public partial class BasketTable
    {
        public BasketTable()
        {
            this.BasketProductTables = new HashSet<BasketProductTable>();
            this.OrderTables = new HashSet<OrderTable>();
        }

        public int BasketId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
        public string SessionId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Registered { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BasketProductTable> BasketProductTables { get; set; }
        public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderTable> OrderTables { get; set; }
    }
public partial class BasketProductTable
    {
        public int BasketProductId { get; set; }
        public int BasketId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> TotalSum { get; set; }

        public virtual BasketTable BasketTable { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductTable ProductTable { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is that I'm uncertain how to merge the baskets. If someone could navigate me to a good article on the subject or show some code then I would be happy. I am coding in Asp.Net (MVC) and using Linq to entity. 
- Jakob

----- UPDATE ------
I decided to use two foreach containing the old and new baskets. I checked on if the item from the new basket existed in the old basket then I would update it with quantity and totalSum. If it didn't exist then I would create a new object with its information and then delete all the items in the old. I found out that the items wouldn't be created/updated in runtime so I had problems checking if a product had been created in the foreach, so I created a list where I would add the created/updated products on their productId and check in the code if the product was added to the list before either creating or updating. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You should not store the contents of the basket to the database. Consider using javascript and store the items to the localStorage. Once logged-in you can retrieve those items from the localStorage. Storing everything in the database isn't a good idea specially if those items isn't guaranteed to be bought by the user.

Comment: @John, it doesn't mean that if he have a Model in there about `Basket` he is going to save it in the Database. He can just use it as a reference Object Model to be passed and work the data's in there. Unless he declares a dataset for the model, then he is creating an Instance of it in the Database.

Comment: so having a Javascript to store the data is irrelevant and SHOULD NOT AND INCORRECT approach in MVC. We should always step away from JS to handle data's that is existing as a Model structure.

Comment: @Aizen You are right, it doesn't mean he will add it to the database but as you can see the models he posted is most likely the entities he uses on his DbSets while he should have posted a view model instead. I don't see anything wrong with using javascript together with MVC. Anyway, in-case he decides to use it, a view model should be used and do something like wazdev's answer for merging.

Comment: if we try to rely on JS to store data, the MVC will become MVW, which we should avoid doing.

Comment: I've been told that storing a basket in a session is bad idea.. My solution was to store the non-logged-in users baskets in a table and have a maintance function that will delete the inactive baskets (30 days old) . Is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that a better experience is to merge the baskets in such a way that "duplicated" orders are ignored. Here's some rough pseudo-code - something like:

```
foreach (BasketProductTable newBasketProduct in newBasket.BasketProductTables) {
   if(oldBasket.Contains(newBasketProduct)) {
      continue; // this ignores duplicate order items
   }

   // Otherwise add it to the old basket
   oldBasket.Add(newBasketProduct);

}
```

Where newBasketTable is your new Basket of goods, and oldBasket is the existing saved basket.

After this you can discard the "new basket" as your "old basket" has the new items. A word of caution: don't forget to re-calculate the price on each individual item, as the price may have changed since the user last placed the item in their basket.

Comment: How would you update the quantity of the duplicate order items?

Comment: Personally, I would not update the quantity for duplicate items- the theory being that the user may be re-adding what they've already added.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer though. I think I'm gonna merge the duplicate products and let the user decide either to purchase them all or update the quantity of them.